# Trying to display a logo from a database field in a bootstrap table column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have tried and tried but I just cannot seem to get it.

I have the following code in a php file using javascript to fill a bootstrap table's columns with data read from another php file (`list-user.php`) which reads the database table into an array and then passes it to this php file. It works fine except for the images. Here is the code fragment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayImage(src, width, height) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    
     var $table = $('#table');
             $table.bootstrapTable({
                  url: 'list-user.php',
                  search: true,
                  pagination: true,
                  buttonsClass: 'primary',
                  showFooter: true,
                  escape: false,
                  minimumCountColumns: 2,
                  columns: [{
                      field: 'num',
                      title: '#',
                      sortable: true,
                  },{
                      field: 'id',
                      title: 'ID',
                      sortable: true,
                  },{
                      field: 'businessName',
                      title: 'Business Name',
                      sortable: true,
                  },{
                      field: 'package',
                      title: 'Package Name',
                      sortable: true,
                  },{
                      field: 'phoneNum',
                      title: 'Phone #',
                      sortable: true,
                  },{
                      field: 'email',
                      title: 'Email',
                      sortable: true,
                  },{
                      align: 'center',
                      formatter: function() {
                        return '<div class="col-md-4"><img class="img" src="{% get_static_prefix %}https://path_to_client/{{ logo }}" alt=""></div>'
                  },
                      field: 'logo',
                      title: 'Logo',
                      sortable: true,
                  }]
             });

</script>
```

The text `https://path_to_client/{{ logo }}` is the url location of my client's website (changed to protect my client) and where the logos are stored. The 'logo' variable is from a mysql table (read into an array from l`ist-user.php`).

The 'logo' field is only part of the img src location. I need to first add the "`https://path_to_client/`" and then the 'logo' variable. The 'logo' variable holds the value '`/logos/name_of_image.png`', so when added, it should look like '`https://path_to_client/logos/name_of_image.png`'

The net result should be the image displayed in a bootstrap table column for each record.

I am able to display a image by hard coding the img src string ("`https://path_to_client/logos/name_of_image.png`") but that does me no good.

How can I change my code so it works?

How do I achieve this?

I tried

```
{
    align: 'center',
    formatter: function() {
        return '<div class="col-md-4"><img class="img" src="{% get_static_prefix %}https://path_to_client/{{ logo }}" alt=""></div>'
    },
    field: 'logo',
    title: 'Logo',
    sortable: true,
}]
```

And it only works if I hard code the img src location.

Again, I am able to display a image by hard coding the img src string ("`https://path_to_client/logos/name_of_image.png`") but that does me no good.

Comment: Can you check your view source, to see what the server is rendering,

Comment: Please tag your questions properly, and/or explain what systems you are using. `{% get_static_prefix %}` is from some library/framework ...? Not sure if using that makes much sense, when you provide an absolute URL starting with `https://` there already?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is directly related to MySQL? You haven't shared any such code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please user this code:

```
formatter: function(value, row) {
    var basePath = "https://path_to_client/"; // Set your base path here
    var logoPath = row.logo; // Assuming 'logo' contains '/logos/name_of_image.png'
    var imageUrl = basePath + logoPath;
    return '<div class="col-md-4"><img class="img" src="' + imageUrl + '" alt=""></div>';
},
```

the formatter function will dynamically generate the correct image source URL for each row in your Bootstrap table based on the value of the logo field.